# Pandas Merge 2 Databases

Tags: pandas, merge

I'm trying to do a merge and am having trouble.

These are my 2 dataframes:

DF1

```
        Team_Id Team_Name   Season  Daynum  Wteam   Wscore  Lteam   
    0   1104    Alabama     1985    137     1104    50      1112    
    1   1104    Alabama     1985    139     1104    63      1433    
    2   1104    Alabama     1986    137     1104    97      1462    
    3   1104    Alabama     1986    139     1104    58      1228    
    4   1104    Alabama     1987    136     1104    88      1299
```

DF2

```
    Season  Seed    Team
 0  1985    X07     1104
 1  1986    Y05     1104
 2  1987    X02     1104
```

I want the seeds from DF2 to be in the rows of DF1. There is more information in DF2 then there is in DF1.

The expected results are:

```
    Team_Id Team_Name   Season  Daynum  Wteam   Wscore  Lteam   Seed
0   1104    Alabama     1985    137     1104    50      1112    X07 
1   1104    Alabama     1985    139     1104    63      1433    X07
2   1104    Alabama     1986    137     1104    97      1462    Y05
3   1104    Alabama     1986    139     1104    58      1228    Y05 
4   1104    Alabama     1987    136     1104    88      1299    X02
```

Comment: Have you tried using [`pd.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) at all?

Comment: You are providing data that cannot be used to produce the output you've given. Please reduce this to a [mcve], or else your problem cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Though it really seems like all you want is `df1.merge(df2[['Seed', 'Team']], on='Team')`

Comment: OK. I changed it to be 2 complete databases. That code didn't work. Maybe because there isn't a 'Team' column in DF1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `merge` with `left_on` and `right_on`:

```
DF1.merge(DF2, left_on=['Season','Team_Id'], right_on=['Season','Team'])
```

Output:

```
   Team_Id Team_Name  Season  Daynum  Wteam  Wscore  Lteam Seed  Team
0     1104   Alabama    1985     137   1104      50   1112  X07  1104
1     1104   Alabama    1985     139   1104      63   1433  X07  1104
2     1104   Alabama    1986     137   1104      97   1462  Y05  1104
3     1104   Alabama    1986     139   1104      58   1228  Y05  1104
4     1104   Alabama    1987     136   1104      88   1299  X02  1104
```

Comment: Thanks, Scott Boston!